# apache LoadBalancer configuration file

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing

I want to specify lbfactor for LoadBalancer members and persist it.  how can this be done?
currently in `httpd.conf`:

```
<Proxy balancer://xxxx>
    BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8009/xxxx
    BalancerMember ajp://yyyyy:8009/xxxx
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<Proxy balancer://xxxx>
    BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8009/xxxx lbfactor=10
    BalancerMember ajp://yyyyy:8009/xxxx lbfactor=20
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Nope, apache fails to start after this change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `loadfactor=X` (instead of `lbfactor`).

Reference: Section *A sample balancer setup* http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass